# Devise's HTTP authentication breaks regular sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cross-browser, logout, basic-authentication

Regular sign in and sign out works fine in my app. However, when I use HTTP Authentication to sign in to access JSON or XML resources and then go back and click the sign out button it redirects me to the login page but the user is still logged in and can access any page. It doesn't log out until I completely close the browser. [This article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicfaq) explains better the problem in general. Does devise have any workaround or this is still an issue?

I have been reading a lot about it and had try the [work arounds here](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TrueHttpLogoutPatch) but didn't work for other than IE. Is there a way to expire the http_authenticatable credentials when the user logs out?

Here are the steps to reproduce the issue.

1. Enable HTTP authentication (config.http_authenticatable = true in config/initializers/devise.rb)
2. Make sure you are log out from the application. Then access a JSON or XML resource. e.g. open localhost:3000/products.json in the browser
3. The browser will popup a message box to enter user name and password. Enter those.
4. Go back to an regular html page. e.g. open localhost:3000/products
5. Click sign out
6. Notice user will still be logged in. Even after deleting the cookie!!

User cannot log out until it closes completely the browser window, this potentially could be a security issue in public places.

testing with devise (2.1.2) and rails (3.2.16)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Cache-Control` header during your JSON / XML response to make it uncacheable. Perhaps that will prevent it from caching the credentials as well.

UPDATE with a specific example of how to make all API calls uncacheable.

In ApplicationController:

```
def set_uncacheable
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
end

before_filter :make_api_calls_uncacheable
def make_api_calls_uncacheable
  set_uncacheable if ['xml', 'json'].include?(request.format)
end
```

Comment: Where in a Rails App should I add this header so all the JSON/XML can have it?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I suspect you could do something like following: in `ApplicationController`, define `set_uncacheable` as shown in my answer above. Then add a before_filter in `ApplicationController` called `set_uncacheable_for_api_calls`, which says something like `set_uncacheable if ['xml', 'json'].include?(request.format)`

Comment: it is caching, or more the browser just holding onto and resending the HTTP AUTH header with ever request.

Comment: I tried sending the header Cache-Control still no good. The browser is still caching the information. I was able to do an HTTP Auth logout in IE using this js command: `document.execCommand('ClearAuthenticationCache', 'false')` however, it doesn't work for Chrome, FF and all others...